# Orbot showing IP adresses on status bar

Tags: applications, tor

I configured Orbot to route every app's traffic through TOR network.
In the status bar, It is showing different IP addressees with country names and agencies.
Also, these listing keeps on changing as the network is alive.

```
/*`For Example */
147.175187.143 Slovac Republic (Zdruzenie pouzivatelov Slovenskej akademickej datovej siete)
37.48.64.48 Netherlands (Leaseweb B.V)
94.23.165.38 Germany (OVH SAS)
91.214.2.0.144 Republic of Moldova (SRL ROXNET-COM)
82.223.16.128 Spain (ARSYS INTERNET S.L.)
104.47.154.74 United States (Microsoft Corporation)
```

All these appeared in a single instance.
Like this the addressees will keep on changing.

What does that actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's your current TOR Circuit. These might change after a while to keep you anonymous while browsing the Internet (or deep web) through TOR.